# Build Report in Excel or Access to show how many hours were accumulated between specific dates

Tags: excel, ms-access, report, formula

I'm hoping someone can help me. I'm trying to create a report or list that will return from a table the number of hours a staff member has accumulated towards the Continuing Ed requirements of each state, within the most recent licensing period (typically 12-24 months).
The hours only count if they fall between the "Start" date and "End" date (last license renewal date, and upcoming expiration date). Start and End Dates vary from State to State.

I have two data tables; the Engineer should act as the "foreign key" for each table.

- One has the Engineer's licensing information for each state, listed by State.

> **STATE---Last Renewal Date ("Start")---Exp Date ("End")--Qty PDH Hrs Reqd---ENGINEER**

> Alabama---------12/31/2021------------------12/31/2023----------30-----------------Engineer #1

- The other has the information about how many hours were earned and on what date, listed by Engineer

> **STATE------Date Hrs Earned---------Qty PDH Hrs Earned----ENGINEER**

> Alabama-------09/20/2022----------------------30---------------Engineer #1

In the end, the result should look like this:

> **ENGINEER 1-----------# Hrs Met**-----------# Hrs Req'd**--------------# Hrs Needed**
>
> - State 1----------------# (number of hours)---------#---------------------#
> - State 2----------------#------------------------------#---------------------#

I've tried using the Data Model and Pivot Table in Excel, and Queries and Reports in Access. I can't figure out how to write a formula that will look up and return the data.

Comment: I don't think you particularly need a Table for this, just SUMIFS with multiple criteria of Engineer and ValidPeriod. Then a new sheet using UNIQUE to display the Engineer, and XLOOKUP to fetch that Engineers info. (Note: If you use VLookup you will need to move the Engineer column to Column 1 as the "Key" column needs to be before any data)

Comment: Why does the output show "State 1" and "State 2"? The source tables show only "Alabama". Why would Engineer 1 list multiple states? Edit question to show more representative data and output that reflects the data.

Comment: Response 1: I will definitely try your suggestions! Thank you!

Response 2: *Why would Engineer 1 list multiple states?*
Each engineer can hold a license for multiple states. We have clients throughout the US and each state has its own engineering standards, so the engineers must carry a license in order to perform work on buildings in those states that require a license.
If I can't get the other suggestions to work, I will revise the question as you recommended.